# What is the difference between log4j-1.2-api and log4j-api (without the 1.2 suffix)

Tags: log4j

[The maven repo for Log4j](https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/logging/log4j/)

Could somebody tell what is the difference between these 2 apis ? I assume the one without 1.2 suffix is the latest.

Answer (score 3):

`Log4j-1.2-api`'s are bridge api's which is used for making the applications which works on `log4j-1.2.xx` to work using `log4j 2

[More Info](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/log4j-2.1/log4j-1.2-api/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

log4j-1.2-api is a brige to let log4j code log to log4j2 logfile. log4j-api is you can use it api in code to log

Comment: So i just only need to remove the log4j-1.2.x in my application, and replace with the bridge log4j-1.2-2.x.jar?   Along with the bridge, do i also need to include log4j-api-2.x. I assume the log4j-core-2.x is NOT needed.